# Setting up VCR for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vcr

I'm currently trying to get VCR to run correctly for my app. Right now everything seems to be configured right but I must be missing something because when the test that uses the `VCR.use_cassette` is not render the response in the yml file I have set up. I'll post all of my code that is pertaining the issue and let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

/support/vcr.rb:

```
    VCR.configure do |c|
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
  c.cassette_library_dir = Rails.root.join("spec", "vcr")
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.after_http_request do |request, _response|
    VCR.http_requests_made << request
  end
end
```

Request spec:

```
 require "rails_helper"

describe "Mailchimp" do
  describe "Manage list" do
    let!(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber) }

    it "adds new subscriber to list" do
      expect do
        VCR.use_cassettes("mailchimp/list") do
          post new_subscriber_path
        end.to change(:subscriber, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

YML file: /vcr/mailchimp/list.yml

```
NOTHING RENDERS. THIS IS WHERE I EXPECT THE RESPONSE FOR VCR BUT I"M GETTING NOTHING.
```

Hopefully this is enough info. let me know if you need more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
VCR.configure do |config|
  config.allow_http_connections_when_no_cassette = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't pin-point what the error might have been in your case, but here are my thoughts:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe "Mailchimp" do
  describe "Manage list" do
    let!(:subscriber) { FactoryGirl.create(:subscriber) }

    it "adds new subscriber to list" do
      expect do
        VCR.use_cassette("mailchimp/list") do
          post new_subscriber_path
        end
      end.to change(:subscriber, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Changes made,

1. Moved the VCR call into the expectation block
2. Changed to `VCR.use_cassete`

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I appreciate The help but that doesn't seem to do the job... although that is some obvious stuff I should have noticed. Thanks